# ORDER BY column by column has sequence

Tags: mysql

Suppose I've got `condition` table with columns like this:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| ID |   Name   | Condition |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Value 1  | NULL      |
|  4 | Value 2  | NULL      |
| 13 | Value 3  | NULL      |
|  8 | Value 4  | 1         |
| 10 | Value 5  | 1         |
| 12 | Value 6  | 1         |
| 17 | Value 7  | 1         |
| 18 | Value 8  | 1         |
| 20 | Value 9  | 1         |
| 21 | Value 10 | 1         |
|  6 | Value 11 | 4         |
| 11 | Value 12 | 4         |
| 16 | Value 13 | 4         |
| 14 | Value 14 | 13        |
| 19 | Value 15 | 13        |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

And now, I want them order `ID` and `Condition` has sequence one by one like this :

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| ID |   Name   | Condition |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Value 1  | NULL      |
|  8 | Value 4  | 1         |
| 10 | Value 5  | 1         |
| 12 | Value 6  | 1         |
| 17 | Value 7  | 1         |
| 18 | Value 8  | 1         |
| 20 | Value 9  | 1         |
| 21 | Value 10 | 1         |
|  4 | Value 2  | NULL      |
|  6 | Value 11 | 4         |
| 11 | Value 12 | 4         |
| 16 | Value 13 | 4         |
| 13 | Value 13 | NULL      |
| 14 | Value 14 | 13        |
| 19 | Value 15 | 13        |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the order. It's not as clear as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange sort order. So records with IDs not present in `Condition` shall be ordered by `Condition` first and then `ID`, while records with IDs present in `Condition` shall be ordered by `ID` and before the records with that ID in `Condition`. One way is to select those two sets with the mentioned sortkeys and use `union all` on the two sets.

```
select id, name, condition
from
(
  select 
    id, 
    name, 
    condition, 
    id as sortkey1, 
    1 as sortkey2, 
    null as sortkey3
  from mytable 
  where id in (select condition from mytable)
  union all
  select 
    id, 
    name, 
    condition, 
    condition as sortkey1, 
    2 as sortkey2, 
    id as sortkey3
  from mytable 
  where id not in (select condition from mytable)
)
order by sortkey1, sortkey2, sortkey3;
```